# How to resolve "Deference of a possible null reference" warning?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, nullable

Working with EF Core 5, Nullable enabled, .NET Core 5.

I am getting a warning when doing this:

myDBContext.Entity.SingleOrDefaultAsync<Entity?>(e => e.Property == value)

The squiggly line for the warning is under the second e in the lambda.

I know I can change the TSource to < Entity>, but I explicitly want this to return nullable Entity so it is clear for the caller that they can get null out of this call, as it is a SingleOrDefault.

I hope that I can resolve this properly, not through ! or a suppress message, any idea?

**Edit**
If you see this example
https://dotnetfiddle.net/baP5JV

The issue isn't there, is this related to EF Core only?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a null conditional operator:

```cs
myDBContext.Entity.SingleOrDefault<Entity?>(e => e != null && e.Property == value)
```

Reference: [Null-conditional operators ?. and ?[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators)

**EDIT:**

Updated to not use null conditional.

Comment: It doesn't, it turns all of e.Property to red/error. "An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagation operator". Any way, I don't really want to resolve with ! or ?

Comment: Edited to show you can do the same thing without the null-conditional operator

Answer (score -1):

Warning gone after adding await to the SingleOrDefaultAsync call and marking the repository method as async.
Not ideal, as I really want to return the Task<Entity?>

I won't accept this answer for now, will see if I get a solution or at least an explanation.